# How to save words in a CSV file tokenized from articles with sentence id number?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, preprocessor

I am trying to extract all words from articles stored in CSV file and write sentence id number and containing words to a new CSV file.

What I have tried so far,

```
import pandas as pd
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
df = pd.read_csv(r"D:\data.csv", nrows=10)

row = 0; sentNo = 0
while( row < 1 ):
    sentences = tokenizer.tokenize(df['articles'][row])
    for index, sents in enumerate(sentences):
        sentNo += 1
        words = word_tokenize(sents)
        print(f'{sentNo}: {words}')
    row += 1
```

`df['articles'][0]` contains:

```
The ultimate productivity hack is saying no. Not doing something will always be faster than doing it. This statement reminds me of the old computer programming saying, “Remember that there is no code faster than no code.”
```

I took only `df['articles'][0]`, It gives output like this:

```
1:['The', 'ultimate', 'productivity', 'hack', 'is', 'saying', 'no', '.']
2:['Not', 'doing', 'something', 'will', 'always', 'be', 'faster', 'than', 'doing', 'it', '.']
3:['This', 'statement', 'reminds', 'me', 'of', 'the', 'old', 'computer', 'programming', 'saying', ',', '“', 'Remember', 'that', 'there', 'is', 'no', 'code', 'faster', 'than', 'no', 'code', '.', '”']
```

How can I write a new `output.csv` file that includes all the sentences from all articles in `data.csv` file in the given format:

```
Sentence No | Word
1             The
              ultimate
              productivity
              hack
              is
              saying
              no
              .
2             Not
              doing 
              something 
              will
              always
              be
              faster
              than
              doing
              it
              .
3             This 
              statement 
              reminds 
              me 
              of 
              the 
              old 
              computer 
              programming 
              saying
              , 
              “
              Remember
              that 
              there
              is
              no
              code
              faster
              than
              no
              code
              .
              ”
```

I am new to Python and using it on Jupyter Notebook.

And this is my first post on Stack overflow. If anything is not in right order, correct me to learn. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just need to iterate through the words and write a new line for each.

Going to be a bit unpredictable since you have commas as "words" as well - might want to consider another delimiter or strip the commas from your words list.

EDIT: This seems like a little cleaner way to do it.

```
import pandas as pd
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize

df = pd.read_csv(r"D:\data.csv", nrows=10)
sentences = tokenizer.tokenize(df['articles'[row]])
f = open('output.csv','w+')
stcNum = 1

for stc in sentences:
  for word in stc:
    prntLine = ','
    if word == stc[0]:
      prntLine = str(stcNum) + prntLine
    prntLine = prntLine + word + '\r\n'
    f.write(prntLine)
  stcNum += 1

f.close()
```

output.csv:

```
1,The
,ultimate
,productivity
,hack
,is
,saying
,no
,.
2,Not
,doing
,something
,will
,always
,be
,faster
,than
,doing
,it
,.
3,This
,statement
,reminds
,me
,of
,the
,old
,computer
,programming
,saying
,,     # <<< Most CSV parsers will see this as 3 empty columns
,“
,Remember
,that
,there
,is
,no
,code
,faster
,than
,no
,code
,.
,”
```

Comment: Thank you @mikah-barnett .I understood your edits but instead of printing, I want to write those in a csv file all together. I am stuck with that part.

Comment: Edited my answer to include a little cleaner version as well as output to a CSV file of your choice.

Comment: It perfectly serves my purpose now. I have just tasted on my data set. And you are very much correct about commas, it was making problems to read newly created csv file. BTW, Thanks a ton @mikah-barnett :D